# Match a specific line in string using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains some substrings seperated by a new line.

Forexample :

```
$x="This is the first line.
      This is the second line.
      This is the third line.";
```

I want to get the third line from this string,

My regex so far :

```
/\s*([^\n]+)/i
```

But this returns the whole string,

I have also tried

```
/\n{3}\s*([^\n]+)/i
```

It matched nothing.

Is there any way in regex to solve my problem? I have been trying to solve it myself for the last 30mnts, but all of my attempts failed.

```
 preg_match_all("/\s*([^\n]+)/i",$x,$m);
print_r($m);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not explode with `\n` and get the last item? A regex is necessary when you have complex patterns. Here, you need to get some specific line.

Comment: Could you provide a full example of the string you are trying to parse since you said this is only a small part of a bigger string you are trying to parse...

Answer (score 5):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the complexity of your situation, you should be able to just use `explode()` like this:

```
$split = explode("\n", $x);
print_r($split[2]);
```

Comment: Also trim the output, since it appears that `$x` contains leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `s` modifier along with `$` . In dotall mode `$` matches the end of very last line.

```
preg_match('~\s*([^\n]+)$~s',$x,$m);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fX9zI1/1)

Comment: You do not need `/s`. I doubt you need a regex at all here.